# JQ rename parts of values in array

Tags: arrays, json, rename, jq

I try to rename the values in an array. However, only parts of them, keeping the other parts. Managed to rename whole strings, but not the "parts-task" using JQ.

JSON input:

```
{
  "values": [
    "foo:bar1",
    "foo:bar2",
    "foo:bar3"
  ]
}
```

desired output:

```
{
  "values": [
    "bar1",
    "bar2",
    "bar3"
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your jq has regex support (e.g. jq 1.5):

```
.values |= map(sub("foo:";"")))
```

Or maybe `"^foo:";` ...